# Qt, странная краснота в редакторе интерфейса

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что обозначает следующая краснота в дизайнере интерфейса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не ошибка, это означает, что обведенные виджеты скомпонованы, все нормально

Comment: Понял, спасибо!